# Kotlin send me this error: For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method

Tags: kotlin

```
data class precioSuper(var producto:String, var precio: Int, val codigoDeBarras:String)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    //Qué vende o super?
    val galletas = precioSuper("galletas", 3, "0001")
    val chocolate = precioSuper("chocolate", 5, "0002")
    val leite = precioSuper("leite", 2, "0003")

    var productos = arrayListOf<String>("galletas", "chocolate", "leite")

    var totalProductos = productos.size
    var codigoDeBarras2 = for(producto in totalProductos)

}
```

in the lane of code var codigoDeBarras2 = for(producto in totalProductos) kotlin send me this error: "For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method"

The error is exactly in "totalProductos" "for(producto in **totalProductos**)"

Comment: `productos.size` doesn't look like a collection to me; it looks like a single value.  You're assigning it to the `totalProductos` variable, and then trying to iterate over it in `for(producto in totalProductos)`.

Answer (score 4):

The error is that you are assigning the `for` loop to a variable.  
`for` **is not an expression** and can't be assigned.  
Also the expression `producto in totalProductos` does not make sense as you treat `totalProductos` like a `Collection` but it is only an integer number. 
If you want to iterate through the items of the list `productos` you can do it:

```
for (producto in productos) {
    //..............
}
```

or

```
for (i in 0 until totalProductos) {
    //..............
}
```

or

```
productos.forEach { 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are trying to "extract" the `producto` property of `productos` list. Then you can try

```
var codigoDeBarras2 = productos.map { it.producto }
```